# The program does not print the result

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Now, I am working with the following program, but I can't get the Image Moments, Centroid etc. that I need.

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy

from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
from numpy import mgrid, sum

image = imread('imagemoment.png')

def moments2e(image):
    assert len(image.shape) == 2  # only for grayscale images
    x, y = mgrid[:image.shape[0], :image.shape[1]]
    moments = {}
    moments['mean_x'] = sum(x * image) / sum(image)
    moments['mean_y'] = sum(y * image) / sum(image)

    # raw or spatial moments
    moments['m00'] = sum(image)
    moments['m01'] = sum(x * image)
    moments['m10'] = sum(y * image)
    moments['m11'] = sum(y * x * image)
    moments['m02'] = sum(x ** 2 * image)
    moments['m20'] = sum(y ** 2 * image)
    moments['m12'] = sum(x * y ** 2 * image)
    moments['m21'] = sum(x ** 2 * y * image)
    moments['m03'] = sum(x ** 3 * image)
    moments['m30'] = sum(y ** 3 * image)

    # central moments
    moments['mu01']= sum((y-moments['mean_y'])*image) # should be 0
    moments['mu10']= sum((x-moments['mean_x'])*image) # should be 0
    moments['mu11'] = sum((x - moments['mean_x']) * (y - moments['mean_y']) * image)
    moments['mu02'] = sum((y - moments['mean_y']) ** 2 * image)  # variance
    moments['mu20'] = sum((x - moments['mean_x']) ** 2 * image)  # variance
    moments['mu12'] = sum((x - moments['mean_x']) * (y - moments['mean_y']) ** 2 * image)
    moments['mu21'] = sum((x - moments['mean_x']) ** 2 * (y - moments['mean_y']) * image)
    moments['mu03'] = sum((y - moments['mean_y']) ** 3 * image)
    moments['mu30'] = sum((x - moments['mean_x']) ** 3 * image)

    # opencv versions
    # moments['mu02'] = sum(image*(x-m01/m00)**2)
    # moments['mu02'] = sum(image*(x-y)**2)

    # wiki variations
    # moments['mu02'] = m20 - mean_y*m10
    # moments['mu20'] = m02 - mean_x*m01

    # central standardized or normalized or scale invariant moments
    moments['nu11'] = moments['mu11'] / sum(image) ** (2 / 2 + 1)
    moments['nu12'] = moments['mu12'] / sum(image) ** (3 / 2 + 1)
    moments['nu21'] = moments['mu21'] / sum(image) ** (3 / 2 + 1)
    moments['nu20'] = moments['mu20'] / sum(image) ** (2 / 2 + 1)
    moments['nu03'] = moments['mu03'] / sum(image) ** (3 / 2 + 1)  # skewness
    moments['nu30'] = moments['mu30'] / sum(image) ** (3 / 2 + 1)  # skewness

    return moments
```

Can you help me solve this problem, please?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I can see at the first glance is, you have defined the function `moments2e(image)` but have not called it. You need to call the `moments2e(image)` function outside the function definition.

```
import cv2
import numpy
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
from numpy import mgrid, sum

image = imread('imagemoment.png')

def moments2e(image):
    assert len(image.shape) == 2  # only for grayscale images
    x, y = mgrid[:image.shape[0], :image.shape[1]]
    .
    .
    .
    return moments
moments = moments2e(image)
print(moments)
```

Comment: C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\opencv_python\python.exe "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Image Moments Code/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Image Moments Code/main.py", line 89, in <module>
    moments = moments2e(image)
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Image Moments Code/main.py", line 10, in moments2e
    assert len(image.shape) == 2  # only for grayscale images
AssertionError

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: That suggests the image you are passing is not grayscale. If you want to convert it to grayscale, add this before your `assert` line: `image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`